# New field types in Gentics Mesh schema

Tags: graph-databases, gentics-mesh

I'd like to add custom field types like 'email' or other strings that could use regex validation.

Also, numeric fields with validation like < or > or formatting like money.

I was thinking about storing a mapping of schema uuid + field name + field type, and have the UI query a new rest api to get the validation and formatting criteria when editing a node?

Does that sound like a good approach? or is there a better one?

I'm new to mesh, so I'm still learning how to approach customizations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this relates to [issue 112](https://github.com/gentics/mesh-incubator/issues/112). At the moment it is not possible to add custom validation or custom field types. In the future more specific constraints can be added. Additionally we also plan to add a "control" property to schema fields. This field can be used to store any JSON. This JSON control property value can in turn be used in the UI to add custom form behavior or control how front-ends display/handle the value.